# On row item click listner for tablelayout in android

Tags: android, json, android-tablelayout

Hi in the below code what i tried is Implemented tablelayout in that it contains dynamic table row coming from server parsing the data and displaying in table format

This is output for which one i was implemented Dynamic table layout contains dynamic data

[image: Dynamic table layout contains dynamic data]

Now In my above screenshot last row contain a named as view if user click that view want to show the file coming from the server .

Can any one help me to resolve this issue

Response from server:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "pan": {
            "id": "52728",
            "filename": "PAN.jpg",
            "path": "storage/2020/January/week3/52728_PAN.jpg"
        },
        "adhar": {
            "id": "52730",
            "filename": "AADHAR.jpg",
            "path": "storage/2020/January/week3/52730_AADHAR.jpg"
        },
        "gst": {
            "id": "52732",
            "filename": "GST.jpg",
            "path": "storage/2020/January/week3/52732_GST.jpg"
        },
        "purchase_order": {
            "id": "52734",
            "filename": "PO1.jpg",
            "path": "storage/2020/January/week3/52734_PO1.jpg"
        },
        "checque": {
            "id": "52736",
            "filename": "ADV.jpg",
            "path": "storage/2020/January/week3/52736_ADV.jpg"
        },
        "doc_one": {
            "id": "53160",
            "filename": "docone.PNG",
            "path": "storage/2020/July/week1/53160_docone.PNG"
        },
        "doc_two": {
            "id": "52740",
            "filename": "PO3.jpg",
            "path": "storage/2020/January/week3/52740_PO3.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
       final APIService service = RetroClass.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIService.class);
        /** Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the notice data*/
        Call<DocumentModel> call = service.GetDocumentList(operation, sessionId, module,record);
        /**Log the URL called*/
        Log.i("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DocumentModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DocumentModel> call, Response<DocumentModel> response) {
                Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    DocumentModel documentModel = response.body();
                    // Gson g = new Gson();
                    //String jsonAllDocuments = g.toJson(documentModel);
                    //  tinyDB.putString("jsonAllDocuments", jsonAllDocuments);
                    String success = documentModel.getSuccess();
                    if (success.equals("true")) {
                        ClosedwonResults closedwonResults = documentModel.getResult();
                        panModel = closedwonResults.getPan();
                        id = panModel.getId();
                        Log.d("docid", id);
                        filename = panModel.getFilename();
                        Log.d("filename", filename);
                        path = panModel.getPath();
                        Log.d("path", path);

                        GSTModel gstModel=closedwonResults.getGst();
                            gstId = gstModel.getId();
                            gstFilename=gstModel.getFilename();
                            gstpath=gstModel.getPath();
                            Purchase_orderModel purchase_orderModel=closedwonResults.getPurchase_order();
                        purchaseId=purchase_orderModel.getId();
                        purchaseFilename=purchase_orderModel.getFilename();
                        purchasePath=purchase_orderModel.getPath();

                        AdharModel adharModel=closedwonResults.getAdhar();
                        adharId=adharModel.getId();
                        adharFilename=adharModel.getFilename();
                        adharPath=adharModel.getPath();


                        ChecqueModel checqueModel=closedwonResults.getChecque();
                        checqueId=checqueModel.getId();
                        checqueFilename=checqueModel.getFilename();
                        checquepath=checqueModel.getPath();

                        Doc_oneModel doc_oneModel = closedwonResults.getDoc_one();
                        doc_oneid = doc_oneModel.getId();
                        Log.d("doc_oneid", doc_oneid);
                        doc_onefilename = doc_oneModel.getFilename();
                        Log.d("doc_onefilename", doc_onefilename);
                        doc_onepath = doc_oneModel.getPath();
                        Log.d("doc_onepath", doc_onepath);
                        Doc_twoModel doc_twoModel = closedwonResults.getDoc_two();
                        doc_twoid = doc_twoModel.getId();
                        Log.d("doc_twoid", doc_twoid);
                        doc_twofilename = doc_twoModel.getFilename();
                        Log.d("doc_twofilename", doc_twofilename);
                        doc_twopath = doc_twoModel.getPath();
                        Log.d("doc_twopath", doc_twopath);
                        docModel = new DocModel(filename,adharFilename,gstFilename,purchaseFilename,checqueFilename,doc_onefilename,doc_twofilename,path,adharPath,gstpath,checquepath,purchasePath,doc_onepath,doc_twopath);
                        closedwonList.add(docModel);



                    }
                  //  DocModel docModel1=closedwonList.get(position);
                    documentIDS = docModel.getFilename() + "," + docModel.getDoc_onefilename() + "," + docModel.getDoc_twofilename() + "," +
                            docModel.getAdharfilename() + "," + docModel.getChecquefilename() + "," + docModel.getGstfilename() + "," + docModel.getPurchasefilename();
                    Paths=docModel.getPath()+","+docModel.getGstpath()+","+docModel.getChecquepath()+","+
                            docModel.getAdharpath()+","+docModel.getPurchasepath()+","+docModel.getDoc_onepath()+","+docModel.getDoctwopath();



                    String[] stringArray2 = {"PAN","AADHAR","GST","PURCHASE ORDER","CHECQUE","dOC ONE","DOC TWO"};
                    TableRow tbrowdoc = new TableRow(getContext());
                    Resources resourcedoc = getContext().getResources();
                    tbrowdoc.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
                    tbrowdoc.addView(getTextView(0, "Title", Color.WHITE, resourcedoc.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                    tbrowdoc.addView(getTextView(0, "File Name", Color.WHITE, resourcedoc.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                    tbrowdoc.addView(getTextView(0, "View/Download", Color.WHITE,resourcedoc.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                    documents.addView(tbrowdoc, getLayoutParams());

                    String[] IDSList = documentIDS.split(",");
                    String[] PathList=Paths.split(",");//path list
                   url="XXXXXXX".concat(String.valueOf(PathList));

                    int arrayDoc = stringArray2.length;
                    TextView tv=new TextView(getContext());
                    tv.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
                    tv.setText(url);
                    tv.setTag(url);

                    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayDoc; i++) {

                        final TableRow tbrowdocdetails = new TableRow(getContext());
                        tbrowdocdetails.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());

                        tbrowdocdetails.addView(getTextView(i + arrayDoc, stringArray2[i], Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));
                        tbrowdocdetails.addView(getTextView(i + arrayDoc, IDSList[i], Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));
                        tbrowdocdetails.addView(getTextView1(i + arrayDoc, "View", Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));


                        documents.addView(tbrowdocdetails);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DocumentModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

private TextView getTextView1(int id, final String title, int color, int bgColor) {
        lblClick = new TextView(getContext());
        lblClick.setId(id);
        lblClick.setText(title.toLowerCase());
        lblClick.setTextColor(color);
        lblClick.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        lblClick.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        lblClick.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
        lblClick.setTag(url);
        lblClick.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
        lblClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.getTag().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        return lblClick;
    }
```

Comment: so you want achieve below??     make 'view' as clickable and open a small view where user see that file?

Comment: @Jigar yes exactly

Comment: @Jigar help me how to make view as clickable

Comment: @Jigar I am able to click the view button but every time giving me same url

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new procedure for the last textview.
below steps.

1. Create onclick listener of TextView. as below.

> 

```
TextView.OnClickListener lblClick = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get ID of that row or pass image name in tag property.
            v.getTag().toString();
        }
}
```

2. now pass image URL or id into label `.settag()` property.
3. And set onclick listener with above given  `.setOnClickListener(lblClick);`. And in that listener method you receive your id or image URL. whatever you pass in tag property.

Comment: 2 point I am confussing where to settag() property to be called

Comment: lblClick.setId(id);  add only for 1 time.  settag is property of textview `lblClick.settag('')`.   where in settag pass necessarydata you wish to use .. and under onclick method. you get all passed data .  ` v.getTag().toString();`

Comment: lblClick.setId(id); same here only should I use lblClick.setTag("View");

Comment: pass image path in .settag() property.

Comment: no... Remove v.getTag().toString(); this line.. in that line you receive your URL. store into string variable and print it.

Comment: How to create one more small view

Comment: yes Removed this line stored into path as a string v.getTag().toString();